# How to execute code after selection of item in a form on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I'm on the form of training_project I have a select2 element:

```
<%= f.input_field :contractId, collection: Contract.all, prompt: 'Convenzione', class: 'form-control select2' %>
```

after the user select  the contract i need to do:

```
<% @contract = Contract.find(@training_project.contractId)
@training_project.farmId = @contract.farmId
@farm = Farm.find(@training_project.farmId) if @training_project.farmId && Farm.exists?(@training_project.farmId) %>
```

All of this for get the farm info in relation with the contract selected.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions, one without JS

The form needs to be submitted to the server. For this you need a route, a controller and an action.

and one with JS:

You will need to register a change event and trigger an AJAX call to an action in a controller (see above).

Please investigate this a bit further and then give more details if you need more help.

Also please note that in Ruby snake_case os preferred over camelCase. So i suggest you change `contractId` to `contract_id` and so on.

Comment: thanks you, I think will do it with AJAX.  Ok, now I change to snake_case.

Comment: i'd go for the non-AJAX solution first. Standard form submit is simpler than AJAX.  But perhaps i don't know enough about the problem.

Comment: The form is too long, in this form there are some field that must be autocompleted after the selection... how can I save value not in the form but got with the AJAX?

Comment: We don't know enough about your app/form.

You can use autocomplete (with or without AJAX, see select2 doc) and then submit the form in normal way. 

I'd start with a plain HTML form. Even when there is some hundred entries in the select. Better try and get something working first. Then add select2 with autocomplete. Then use AJAX (if required) to execute the search on server side.